# Mongodb's geoNear In Flask and Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am using flask and  mongoengine. How do I use [mongodb's geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) query?

I am trying to use pymongo like this using this [link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/geo.html?highlight=geonear#querying):

```
db.command(SON([('geoNear', 'content'), ('near', coordinate)]))
```

If I am on the right way.

How do I create pymongo's db object from flask and  mongoengine?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the sourcecode of mongoengine

in connection.py get_db return the db object I need

```
def get_db(alias=DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME, reconnect=False):
```

So I can run geoNear in mongoengine like this:

```
from mongoengine.connection import get_db
get_db().command(SON([('geoNear', 'content'), ('near', coordinate)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine 0.8 introduces [Geo queries](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=geo#geo-queries).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
content.objects(point__near=coordinate)
content.objects(point__near={"type": "Point", "coordinates": coordinate})
```